# What's the purpose or use of tag [world-building]?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of now (2016-02-10 20:04 UTC -6), there are 4 questions tagged with [world-building](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building), but it's not clear to me what [topic or category](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) it defines, *based on those (4) questions it has been used*.

I imagine it used when somebody asks about "[hypothetical or fictional planets, or alternate Earths](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1517/5293)". Still, it might not be the most appropriate tag, since I suppose (rather, speculate) that the motivation for most of such questions is not necessarily "world building" in the sense of, e.g., a science-fiction work, but more for modeling or simple curiosity.

And what about some [homeworks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)? (e.g., [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/7467/5293)) Should they be tagged [world-building](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears those questions are about hypothetical/fictional planets.  It appears there is some consensus that [such questions are on-topic](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1517/6), but I'm not sure whether [world-building](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building) is a good tag to use.  The purpose of modelling a hypothetical/fictional planet is not to write a science fiction novel, as questions on World Building SE are.  The purpose is to better understand processes within a model.

I welcome suggestions for alternative tag names and we can rename/remove the [world-building](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-building) tag.

Comment: What about "hypothetical-planet"? It might be good for hypothetical/alternate Earth too.

Comment: @gerrit: To avoid confusion with the SE World Building site maybe a name change for the tag would be a good thing. I initially thought of world-creating, but that could be problematic, then I thought maybe world-modelling. Terra-forming is a related but different subject.